# CSS for header image, centered, max width %

Tags: css, head

I have a gif to use in a header and have been able to place it with html however, I cannot center it and would like to take advantage of the max width 100% to account for smaller screen sizes. Img src makes the GIF too large on small screens making a scroll bar. I am fairly new to CSS and have not found the answers so far. It is for code injection in squarespace.

Comment: show your html and css code.

Comment: Again, very new to this. But I initially used img src "URL of GIF" which does work and is placed in the header. However as I've learned, align center does not affect an image. Also when viewed in an iPhone it is creates a scroll bar to see all of it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Use margin:auto on your gif to make it centered horizontally. You can also use div instead of img tag and use background-image property.

Comment: Will style=max width 100% account for screen size?

Comment: You can add display block to the img in Css or just use it as background in a div, as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

See here, this is a full out demo:

```
h1{text-align:center;
    background-image:url('http://www.liveside.net/wp-  content/images/archive/2008/01/hackspacesblogbkground_2.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
  box-shadow:3px 4px 2px #000;
  max-width:850px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

click on the pic and see what happens.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/dYKxgW

You will just have to set your max-width on the relevant meia queries.